# Excluding unique indexes in insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, transactions, ddl

Suppose I have a table:

```
create table sample(
i int(5) primary key auto_increment,
a int(5) not null unique,
b int(5) not null unique,
c int(5) not null unique);
```

Also suppose this table can contain millions of records, and many times millions of records can be added or updated. For this task, I plan to use insert on duplicate key update.

Columns a, b, and c are unique columns, but I might have to exchange the column values of b and c across the table. For example:

a b c
1 2 3
2 4 5

I would like to exchange column b's values. I would like to update it to:

a b c
1 4 3
2 2 5

Now, throughout the insert on duplicate key update operation, the value of column a can't change. But columns b and c can.

For this reason, I'd like to just use the index of column a in the insert on duplicate key update, not all index. That is, when insert on duplicate key update decides to update a row, the query should be:

```
update sample set a=?, b=?c=? where a=?
```

rather than

```
update sample set a=?, b=?c=? where a=? or b=? or c=?
```

\Is it possible?

One way I thought of doing this is to just drop the indexes before executing the query and putting the indexes back again.

```
alter table sample drop index b;
alter table sample drop index c;
// query
alter table sample add unique b;
alter table sample add unique c;
```

However, if I'm inside a transaction, this would cause an implicit commit, I would not like that at all.

Is there a better way of doing what I want?

Comment: if a is unique your first sample doesn't work...

Comment: @Florian Koch fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a unique index on the *combination* of values, not on each individual column (at least, your sample data suggests this).

If so, then you need to define the table as:

```
create table sample (
    i int(5) primary key auto_increment,
    a int(5) not null,
    b int(5) not null,
    c int(5) not null,
    unique (a, b, c)
);
```

Comment: doesn't this cause something like (3,2,1) to be inserted if (1,2,3) already exist? The combination of indexes means that the unique constraint is applyed to all values together right? I would like all values to be separately unique.

Comment: @morbidCode . . . Your example data is then not correct.

Comment: I fixed it now.